# Prinitng out the last lines from input Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

Ok i have a task to finish and it's passing 50% of tests, but i have no idea how to pass the rest.

I have to print out the last 5 lines from input and if there are less than 5 lines then just print all. If the last line contains newline character i should assume there is no empty line after that.

Example
Input:

```
bin:            root
daemon:         root
adm:            root
lp:             root
sync:           root
shutdown:       root
halt:           root
mail:           root
news:           root
uucp:           root
operator:       root
hacker:         root
```

Output:

```
mail:           root
news:           root
uucp:           root
operator:       root
hacker:         root
```

So far my code is:

```
String processInput(String input) {
            String[] lines = input.split("\n");
            int len = lines.length;            

            String[] results = new String[5];
            if(len <= 5) {
                results = Arrays.copyOf(lines, 0);
            } else {
                results = Arrays.copyOfRange(lines, len-5, len);
            }

            String c = "";
            for(String s : results){
                c += s + "\n";
            }

            return c;
    }
```

but still it s not working and i don t quite get what they expect me to do with it. Can any one tell me what am i missing?

```
Sample test failed! Result in diff format:
5c5
< hacker:         root
\ No newline at end of file
---
> hacker:         root
```

Comment: Well, you are adding an extra newline at the end of the string. Easiest thing to do: `return c.trim();`. Slightly more involved thing: only add the newline for the first 4 lines, not the last one.

Comment: HEY IT WORKS! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a newline on the end of each line you append to `c`, which also means that you are adding one on the very end of the string, and there isn't one present in the input.

The hacky way to fix this is simply to trim your output:

```
return c.trim();
```

However, it might not work for some inputs, e.g. with lines that are supposed to end with whitespace.

Alternatively, you can remove just the last character:

```
return c.substring(0, c.length() - 1);
```

However, you don't need to add that new line in the first place (nor do you need the array copy):

```
for (int i = Math.max(0, lines.length - 5); i < lines.length - 1; ++i) {
  c += lines[i] + "\n";
}
c += lines[lines.length - 1];
```

Actually, you don't need the split either, you can operate directly on the input string. Also, you should use `StringBuilder` to accumulate string fragments in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly because I can't help myself, here is an example of how you could implement this using Java 8 streams:

```
String processInput(String input) {
  String[] lines = input.split("\n");
  int start = Math.max(0, lines.length - 5);
  return Arrays.stream(lines, start, lines.length).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
}
```